# Xcode: iOSUndefined symbols for architecture x86_64 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, xcode8

I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_hmac_sha1", referenced from:
      -[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider signClearText:withSecret:] in OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider.o
  "_Base64EncodeData", referenced from:
      -[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider signClearText:withSecret:] in OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the line is complaining about:

```
extern void hmac_sha1(const u_int8_t *inText, size_t inTextLength, u_int8_t* inKey, const size_t inKeyLength, u_int8_t *outDigest);
```

I can not figure what is wrong or how can I fix this issue.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a library or framework.  Select your Project in the project navigator, go to the General tab, and scroll down to Linked frameworks and libraries.  Click the `+` symbol to add a framework or library to your project.

hmac_sha1 is part of the Common Crypto library, so that looks like a good place to start.

Comment: What is complaining "_hmac_sha1", referenced from" is this part "extern void hmac_sha1(const u_int8_t *inText, size_t inTextLength, u_int8_t* inKey, const size_t inKeyLength, u_int8_t *outDigest);"

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, these clang errors are a bit general. Most often I see these when I get naming collisions. Most recently I updated a framework to its newer version, and ended up getting both a class name collision and an extern NSString * const, which from what you said above could likely be your problem. I'd do a search for "hmac_sha1" in your codebase and see what shows up. Maybe even change the name and run it again.